# declaring class in controller

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading an Objective-C Fundamentals book that's taking me through the construction of a basic app. However, it doesn't always show us what to do. At one point, it says

> open RootViewController.h and remove the existing definitions for the PropertyType enumeration and RentalProperty structure. Replace them with the CTRentalProperty class.

Ok, it's easy to find the enumeration and structure it referred to...

```
typedef enum PropertyType {

    Unit,
    TownHouse,
    Mansion
} PropertyType;

typedef struct {

    NSString *address;
    PropertyType type;
    double weeklyRentalPrice;

} RentalProperty;
```

but what exactly does it mean (what is the actual code) when it says

> Replace them with the CTRentalProperty class

Do I just write

```
CTRentalProperty;
```

Probably not. Can you help me understand what the author's talking about. We've made **CTRentalProperty.h** and **CTRentalProperty.m** classes/files, but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to copy code from them into the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it means to put

```
@interface CTRentalProperty : NSObject
{
    NSString *address;
    PropertyType type;
    double weeklyRentalPrice;
}
@end
```

into `CTRentalProperty.h` in place of the `struct` definition.  You'll then need to put

```
@implementation CTRentalProperty

@end
```

into `CTRentalProperty.m`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `enum`, but the author probably means something like this:

```
@interface CTRentalProperty : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic, assign) PropertyType type;
@property(nonatomic, assign) double weeklyRentalPrice;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after discovering author provides source code.  Although it doesn't seem to make sense given the instructions he provided in the book. Here's what the controller's supposed to look like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSDictionary *cityMappings;
    NSArray *properties;
}

@end
```